# printf() seems to be destroying my data

Tags: c, gdb, nginx

I'm writing an nginx module in C and am having some super bizarre results. I've extracted a function from my module to test its output as well as the relevant nginx type/macro definitions.

I'm building a struct in my `build_key_hash_pair` function, then doing a `printf()` on the contents in `main`. When I `printf` the data inside the inner function, `main`'s output is valid. When I remove the `printf` inside the inner function, `main` prints an empty string. This is confusing because after the function call to `build_key_hash_pair` I am not operating on the data except to display it. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct ngx_str_t {
    size_t          len;
    char            *data;
} ngx_str_t;

typedef uintptr_t   ngx_uint_t;

typedef struct key_hash_pair {
    ngx_uint_t      hash;
    ngx_str_t       key;
} key_hash_pair;

#define ngx_string(str)     { sizeof(str) - 1, (char *) str }
#define ngx_str_set(str, text)                                               \
    (str)->len = sizeof(text) - 1; (str)->data = (char *) text
#define ngx_hash(key, c)    ((ngx_uint_t) key * 31 + c)
#define ngx_str_null(str)   (str)->len = 0; (str)->data = NULL

void build_key_hash_pair(key_hash_pair *h, ngx_str_t api_key, ngx_str_t ip);

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ngx_str_t api_key = ngx_string("86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8");
    ngx_str_t ip = ngx_string("123.123.123.123");

    key_hash_pair *pair;
    pair = malloc(sizeof(key_hash_pair));
    build_key_hash_pair(pair, api_key, ip);

    printf("api_key = %s\n", api_key.data);
    printf("ip = %s\n", ip.data);

    printf("pair->key = %s\n", pair->key.data);
    printf("pair->hash = %u\n", (unsigned int)pair->hash);

    return 0;
}

void build_key_hash_pair(key_hash_pair *h, ngx_str_t api_key, ngx_str_t ip)
{
    ngx_str_null(&h->key);

    char str[56];
    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
    strcat(str, api_key.data);
    strcat(str, ip.data);
    ngx_str_set(&h->key, str);

    ngx_uint_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < 56; i++) {
        h->hash = ngx_hash(&h->hash, h->key.data[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I do a `printf("hello")` inside the `build_key_hash_pair` function:

```
helloapi_key = 86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8
ip = 123.123.123.123
pair->key = 86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8123.123.123.123
pair->hash = 32509824
```

And here is the (bizarre) output when I do NOT `printf` inside `build_key_hash_pair`:

```
api_key = 86f7e437faa5a7fce15d1ddcb9eaeaea377667b8
ip = 123.123.123.123
pair->key = 
pair->hash = 32509824
```

As you can see, `pair->key` has no data. In gdb, if I breakpoint right after the call in main to `build_key_hash_pair`, `pair->key` contains the appropriate data. But after the first call to `printf`, it is blanked out. The memory address stays the same, but the data is just gone. Can anyone tell me what in the world I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but where are your null terminators for each of these strings?

Comment: String constants do not require an explicit null byte at the end. These are added by the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is a problem:

```
ngx_str_set(&h->key, str);
```

Here `str` is a local variable, and you are putting a pointer to it inside `h->key`, which will be returned to the caller. After `build_key_hash_pair` returns, the pointer will no longer be valid. When you didn't call any other function, the pointer happened to still point to the same value, but this is not something you can rely on. The call to `printf` overwrote that part of the stack.

What you need is either to dynamically allocate the string with `malloc` or `strdup`, or put an array inside the `key_hash_pair` struct to hold the key (possible if the key is always the same size).

Comment: That is good to know for sure, but why on earth if I printf("hello") in the build function does main print pair->key just fine?

Comment: And I'm assuming the solution is to memcpy `str` into the struct?

Comment: @localshred: I already edited my answer to answer both these questions before you even asked them :)

Comment: Ok, using this (and other answers), I've modified main to malloc space for `pair->key.data` and changed `build_key_hash_pair` to `strcat` directly into `h->key.data`. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @localshred: Just make sure your code that frees a key_hash_pair pointer frees the key.data pointer first, otherwise you will leak memory.

Answer (score 2):

`build_key_hash_pair` uses stack-based array `str` to populate the `data` field in the key of `h`.  When you exit from the function, that pointer is no longer valid since `str` goes out of scope.

Your results could be anything from apparently correct operation to a program failure.  `printf` in the function will work, but definitely not if called afterwards.  `ngx_str_set` needs to allocate memory and copy the `text` string into it (to be freed later of course).

I would replace all those macros with functions or inline code, personally.

Comment: Replacing them won't work as they're what I have to work with in the nginx source. Not my code.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I dislike them because it's impossible to set a breakpoint on a particular part of a macro.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `build_key_hash_pair` function, specifically with the stack variable `char str[56];` which is assigned to the `key_hash_pair` via the macro `ngx_str_set`.

Since the stack frame containing `char str[56];` disappears when the function returns, all bets are off for the value of of the pair's data once the function ends.